# Spark structured streaming: Start at most recent version/snapshot ot delta table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I hope you can help me with my problem.
When a spark structured streaming job gets corrupted, i.e. mismatch between delta log and checkpoint file, or the referenced snapshot version does not exist anymore etc., I would like to have a way to restart the streaming job without deleting checkpoint files and transaction logs.

Is there a way to start a structured streaming job and tell Spark to start at the most recent version of the delta table and afjust the checkpoint file accordingly? Losing some data is not that much of a problem in my case, restarting the streaming job is more important.

I couldn't find anything in the spark docs, that lead to a satisfying solution.

Thanks in advance